# How to redirect to html page in passport authentication with Node.js to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using Customcallback of passport.js in Mean Stack Application.I have managed to called the app.post from angular controller and passport operation i did.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl',
 function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $location)
 {
     $scope.LoginClick = function () {

         $http.post('/login', $scope.login).success(function(response){

             $location.path('/home.html');

     })
     .error(function(err){
         $scope.error_message = err;
     });
     };
 });
```

In server.js

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
   if (err) { return next(err); }
   if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
  req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
   return res.redirect('/home.html);
 });
})(req, res, next);
});
```

But here the redirect from node is not working and how to pass them to angular controller. If it is authenticated or success to home.html and if error redirect to login page with error message.

Can anyone help to solve.

Comment: Just redirect to '/' and put check in angular controller you need set session/cookie after successful login. And check always that cookie to redirect into home page of angular

Comment: @Love-Kesh can you explain with example of check. I mean response from node to angular to check

Comment: you need get login user data in response of login api then set that user in cookie to check user is logged in . Also need to clear that cookie when user logout.

Comment: That was handling by passport js right

Comment: passport is handling all these at server side at node js not client(angular) side. you need to do manually.

Comment: can u post some code in answer to set the cookie and in getting in angular controller

Answer (score 0):

In server.js, if authenticated should return 200 http status code and do nothing.

Redirect action should execute on the angular(client), server only return success or fail.

server.js

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      res.writeHead(401, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      return res.end();
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      return res.end();
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: In angular how to fetch res from node and how to validate in angular success or failure

Comment: @charantej Not need fetch res from node, `$http.post().success()` when server return 2xx http status code run it, `$http.post().error()` when server return not 2xx http status code run it.

Comment: I have also thought the same but it is always running the success. in console i seen post /login and status is 302

Comment: server.js should update. [NodeJS Docs http_event_response](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_response).